# Paste MS Word revisions into Excel with VBA, maintaining formatting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting, export

I've searched without success for how to do this...any help much appreciated.

I've written a VBA macro that will go through an MS Word doc, identify each *revision* (eg, deletion/insertion), and put the revised text into a table in a new Word doc.  In the additional table columns, I put additional relevant information like the original (pre-revision) text, the name/initials of the reviser, page number of the revision, etc.

**I want to do the same thing but put the info into Excel instead**, *while retaining the formatting for* revisions (underscore=insertion,strikethrough = deletion).   I know this must be possible because when I 'manually' copy-and-paste my new 'revision table' into Excel, the formatting I want is preserved.  But when I try to code this step, that doesn't happen.  Tried recording a macro as I manually cut-and-pasted, but it didn't really help.

Here's my code to put the info into a new Word doc:

```
 Sub TabulateRevisions()
        Dim oDoc As Document, nDoc As Document
        Dim PP As Paragraph
        Dim SS As Range
        Dim RR As Revision
        Dim r As Long, n As Long
        r = 2
        n = 1


Set oDoc = ThisDocument
    oDoc.ActiveWindow.View.MarkupMode = wdInLineRevisions
        'Need to set this off so the cut and paste gets carries teh inserts and deletions
        If oDoc.TrackRevisions = True Then
            oDoc.TrackRevisions = False
        End If

        Documents.Add
Set nDoc = ActiveDocument
nDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        nDoc.Tables.Add nDoc.Range, 1, 10

    For Each PP In oDoc.Paragraphs
            For Each SS In PP.Range.Sentences
                For Each RR In SS.Revisions
                    'If RR.Type = 1 Or RR.Type = 2 Then 'uncomment to restrict revision types
                    SS.Select
                    On Error Resume Next 'this is just to prevent an error message telling me 'selection is marked as deleted'
                    SS.Copy

                    nDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add
                    nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 1).Range.Select
                    Selection.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
                    nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 2).Range.Select
                    Selection.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
                    nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 3).Range.Text = SS.Text
                    nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 4).Range.Text = RR.Range.Text
                    nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 6).Range.Text = r
                    If RR.Type = 1 Then
                        nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 7).Range.Text = "insertion"
                    ElseIf RR.Type = 2 Then
                        nDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r, 7).Range.Text = "deletion"
                    End If
                    r = r + 1
                    ' End If
                Next RR
            Next SS
        Next PP

        'Code below rejects all revisions in col 2 of nDoc table--these remain in col 1
        Dim CC As Cell
        For Each CC In nDoc.Tables(1).Columns(2).Cells
            n = n + 1
            For Each RR In CC.Range.Revisions
                RR.Reject
            Next RR
        Next CC
    End Sub
```

Sorry; that's a bit long.  I've tried to tweak this code so that instead of creating a new Word doc, it opens an Excel wb and puts the info in there.  For the non-formatted info that's no problem, but I can't figure out how to retain formatting, like I did in col 1 of my nDoc.Tables(1).  I've tried various approaches, such as:

```
xlWB.worksheets(1).Cells(r, 1).Select 'or:
xlWB.worksheets(1).Cells(r, 1).Activate 'followed by:
ActiveSheet.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting) 'and various other permutations of Word style commands
'or:
ActiveSheet.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'and various other permutations of Excel-style commands
```

I've even resorted to trying to code to simply copy-and-paste my nDoc.Tables(1) into Excel (as that actually works when I do it manually), but no success.

Any advice?  I should probably mention that I've got Office 2010, Windows 8.

Thanks to anyone who's read this far!

Comment: Doesn't toggling the track revisions to false mean that it won't show the strikethroughs and underlines etc?

Comment: You'd kind of think so, but that's what made it work for me.   (I just realised I had accidentally duplicated this command for nDoc--before the object was even set!--so I've got rid of that.)

Comment: My current understanding is this:  when you cut-and-paste from one Word doc (oDoc, in the code above) to another (nDoc), **if you want to retain track-change formatting,** then you have to switch track changes **off** first (in the source document, that is).  This is true whether you're manually cut-and-pasting or whether you do it with code.  The code to switch it off in the code above is:  oDoc.TrackRevisions = False.